# Javascript remove item from DOM before rendering code

Tags: javascript, html, nodelist

I'm trying to remove an element from my HTML document, which I'm able to do with the `remove` method, however, when console logging the NodeList with `document.querySelectorAll()` on some classes on elements that should've been removed, they're still showing up in the NodeList.

I need to remove an element from the webpage, but also from the NodeList, as if the element wasn't there initially on page load to prevent the rest of my application from thinking that it's there.

I would've thought that the `remove` method would've covered this, but unfortunately it doesn't, what am I missing and what's the workaround?

```js
function removeElement (ident) {
  const elem = document.querySelector(ident)
  if (elem) {
    elem.remove()
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. [`remove()` definitely removes the element from the nodelist.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc8qx01z/)

Comment: Do you actually call document.querySelectorAll() after removing the element from the document? Asking this since contrary to most other selection methods, document.querySelectorAll() doesn't return a live NodeList - but just a snapshot of the elements that matched the selector at the time it was called.

Comment: I remove the elements prior to calling querySelectorAll

Comment: `querySelector` returns **one** element, so only one element is removed. That's why there is an `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to get elements by their id name.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myid');
elem.remove()
```

here 'myid' is the id of the item to be deleted.

if you want to delete it using query selector then take the help of elem's parent element.

```
let elem = document.querySelector(ident);
elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem);
```